# Contentscript not running on AJAX intense pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I've noticed that my extensions contentscript doesn't appear to run if the page I'm dealing with has a large amount of AJAX on it. For example Gmail / Google Doc's... Why is this? Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Perhaps Google just decided to disable content scripts on their own websites. Are you sure it is because of AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and Docs has iframes all over the place.

Make sure you place `"all_frames": true`in the [Content Script Manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration)

Comment: Doesn't appear to of fixed my issue :( ContentScript isn't running at all